# Mouse over for jquery for a TD to change background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make a box with a DIV an invisible TD inside of it that will allow me to "draw" inside of it, but when you mouse over I want it to leave a trail of changing color. I'm having a really hard time with it.

I'm not looking for a direct answer, a but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong and what I can look into and piece together to fix it.

Thank you! My code is below.

```
<head>
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='outter'>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="test">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('td').mouseover=function() 
    {
        var td = $('#test');
        td.stop()
        .css("background-color","yellow");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#outter 
{
    height: 260px;
    width: 450px;
    border: 1px black solid;
}

td 
{
    height: 260px;
    width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking I need to somehow make my TD bigger, or maybe turn it into a grid? I want it to be fine though, kind of like an etch-a-sketch.

Comment: `So I'm writing a box with a DV with a box with a boarder ` ooooook Why don't you use simply CSS only? No JS is needed for a simple  `:hover`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Fixed. I'm trying to use the JQ to make the background change on mouse over(hover). Later I'll be adding some buttons and a few other things.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If I call .test:hover{background-color: green} will that draw a line when I hover over my invisible TD?

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery is wrong.

```
$('td').mouseover=function() {
    var td = $('#test');
    td.stop()
    .css("background-color","yellow");
}
```

Should be:

```
$('td').mouseover(function() {
    var td = $('#test');
    td.css("background-color","yellow");
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

I'm also not sure why you have that `stop()` in there.

Comment: Still not getting any color from the box.

Comment: Woops, I may not have made it clear, I want it to only make a line, not change the whole background. Like a line that follows the mouse.

Comment: Do you mean like an underline?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems right off the bat.

For your HTML, you are looking for a grid to draw on, but you only have one cell. You want something like.
`<table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>`, which is a 5x5. It should at least work well for testing.

Then your mouseover will need to be changed. You want to capture the `this` object, as that is the `td` you are mousing over, and I am not sure why you are using `stop`.
`$('td').bind('mouseover', function(){$(this).css("background-color","yellow");})`

Here is a fiddle with these changes, and a few more tweaks (http://jsfiddle.net/66g7edyz/).

Comment: Still not getting color with this either.